# giving garbage value while trying to store a md5 hash in a file in python

Tags: python

```
m=md5.new() 
a=10111011
>>> m.update(str(a))
>>> k=m.digest()
>>> k
'\xec\x9d1\x89e\x08\xa1\xc2Y\xf6\xbf6\xfe\xe4\xe2M'
>>> f.write(str(k))
>>> f.flush()
```

the file f is filled with garbage value which i cant use to read again for further use of the hash . Why does it give the garbage value when on the python terminal it gives proper output?And the worst part is file goes corrupt ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want further clues where your "garbage" (your digest!) is coming from, try `print k` versus `print repr(k)`!

You have a raw byte string. I think you want to insert a hexdigest instead? Either use `k = m.hexdigest()` or `k = repr(m.digest())` and write that to your file.

Basically, you can choose your representation, choose what you write to your file. Which of these do you want to see?

```
>>> print k
�1���Y�6���M
>>> print repr(k)
'\xec\x9d1\x89e\x08\xa1\xc2Y\xf6\xbf6\xfe\xe4\xe2M'
>>> print k.encode("hex")
ec9d31896508a1c259f6bf36fee4e24d
```

Pass exactly the same to f.write(..) as you do to print. As you can see, in the original version you used 'k' ('str(k)' is the same as just 'k')

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you're on Windows and haven't properly opened the file in *binary* mode, i.e., as `'wb'`.  We can't tell, since you don't show us how you opened `f`.

Another possibility might be that you're on Python 3 (where `str` means unicode), but I think in that case you'd see a leading `b` when you show `k` (and there's no `md5` module in Python 3's standard library).

Opening the file the right way, with Python 2.6.4 on a Mac, I see the digest as

```
'\x82s\xf9\xa4\x83\x04\x87\xd0\xfdg\xee\xfa\x1f\x05B>'
```

both as `k` and as the file's contents.  I don't know why you're seeing something that different, by the way; I get the same result with Python 2.4 and 2.5.

Comment: Now trying on Linux I get the same identical result as in my answer, both for `k` and the file's contents -- i.e., your problem just can't be reproduced.  Try making a complete, self-contained script (including the opening and closing of the file) to reproduce your problem, and edit your question to show such a self-contained reproduction of the problem, rather than an incomplete fragment which (per se, assuming all surrounding code is right) exhibits no errors.

Comment: as you can see in the code that i have given . i have typed it in the python terminal . so its very much the condensed version .. what ouput i am getting is this        �ZV�a�e젳|�����1�e��Y��6���M

even though i change it to wb ..

Comment: Congratulations to the 100k! :-)